# Firefox extension to display an inline css class or id definition?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

I use Firebug and Web Developer Firefox extensions. One feature I am looking for and which I am not sure if they exist in these extensions is when I am looking at a webpage source, I want to click on a class or id name and somewhere it displays the definition of that class or id. Not the css inheritance hierarchy. Just the particular class or id if they exist

For example:

.....
I click on "header" and I get the css definition or it tells me there are none. I want to filter the css tree hierarchy to just display that class.

Any extensions can do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it displays the definition of that class or id"? E.g. would you want only the CSS selector that matches "#header" exactly, or any selector which contains "#header"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) [can do that](http://getfirebug.com/html.html). Open the HTML-tab, select the element you are interested in. Look in the right box of the firebug window under the style-tab. There you will see each style applied to the element be it by id, class or any other type of selector. You can also check out the layout-tab to see the offset, margin, padding and width of the selected element.

For instance, here on StackOverflow, when I click on the *body*-element, I see the following:

```
body {           /* File: all.css?v=3496 (row 1) */
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:80%;
    text-align:center;
}
body {           /* File: all.css?v=3496 (rad 1) */
    line-height:1;
}
/* + A lot of reset styles for all elements */
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I did mention that I do not want to see the css hierarchy and that's what Firebug displays. I want to click on the class name, not on the element.

Comment: Oh alright, my bad. But Firebug will still show you whether the class/id has any styles in the style-tab. If you can't find the class/id listed there, then it doesn't have any styles declared...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do it from the source (I don't believe) but does do it on the page.  Would CSSViewer help?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2104